# cannot verify domain with bitly

Tags: .htaccess, url-shortener, verify, bit.ly, a-records

Last night I purchased a new domain with the intention of turning it into a vanity url service for my blog!

I created the a record on both cpanel and my domain registrar to point to bit.ly. This morning  however once the domain had propagated I went to verify my domain with bitly and was still getting the same message...

> Short Domain verification failed for "bblg.in". Neither an A Record
>   nor a CNAME record was found.

I went to to domain in chrome and I am getting a 403 forbidden page however if I goto the www. version of that domain it automatically redirects to bitly.com

Weirdly if I visit the non-www version of that domain on chrome on my android mobile device that redirects to the mobile version of bitly.com but if i visit www.bblg.in on my mobile I get a 403 forbidden page.

I assume there is some redirect issue going on which is preventing me to verify my domain with bitly and would probably need a .htaccess file on there! Also to confirm there is nothing in the bblg.in file on my server just a cgi-bin file that automatically gets placed there.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks
- Phillip Dew

Comment: Can you share how did you work it out?